# How do I navigate between different pages in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms

I've made a short XamarinForms project, and I should now have to navigate between sites. Meaning the ideal version would be a message box, on which I then can click on "k" in order to get to another xamarinforms listview page.

Another problem is, that I don't know how to include a message box in there.

But since I'm a beginner in this, I don't know how to do that?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HelloListView
{
public partial class ListViewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public ListViewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HelloListView.ItemsSource = new List<Element>
        {
            new Element {Title = "School 1", Description = "Teacher 1 1"}, new Element {Title = "School 2", Description = "Teacher 2"}
        };
    }

};
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm voting to close this question. This isn't only very basic knowledge that is available everywhere, it also shows no effort from your part. Please see the [StackOverflow documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to submit a well-formed question.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/